# Is it possible to check if a session has been created?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I was trying to check if a new session has been created using the telethon library.

My first idea was to get the warning message from Telegram (New access: [...]), so when I get that kind of message, I know that another device has connected to my account.
I couldn't get that message, so I tried to get it another way:

```
chat = client.get_entity(777000) # Telegram chat id
print(chat)
for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
    print(message.text)
```

(This is not the full code.)

The only message I was able to retrieve was the confirmation code, but only with that I can't do anything.

Another idea was to continuously receive the list of active sessions (using `GetAuthorizationsRequest()`) and, if that list changed, it means that a new device has connected to my account. But is it convenient to continuously send requests to Telegram servers?

I searched everywhere but couldn't find a good solution to my problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tested, but I think you receive a `events.NewMessage(777000)`. See https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html.

Comment: I've already tried it, but the only message I get through the API is the confirmation code, not the warning of a new session.

Comment: You can try `events.Raw`. It may be a different update type.

Comment: You can post your solution and mark it as the answer for other people who have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Lonami, I was able to solve my problem.
With `client.iter_messages(chat)`, I could only view messages, while the "message" I was looking for was an `UpdateServiceNotification`, so I used `events.Raw` to get all types of updates.

Here is the code:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events
from telethon.tl.types import UpdateServiceNotification
api_id = 123456
api_hash = "42132142c132145ej"

with TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash) as client:
   @client.on(events.Raw(func = lambda e: type(e) == UpdateServiceNotification))
   async def handler(event):
      print("New Login!")
   client.run_until_disconnected()
```